# creating 3d polyline from series of points and a 3dpolyline

Tags: autocad

I have a series of points and a 3dpolyline. How can I connect these to get 3dpolylines.

I don't want to click on every single point to join 3dpolyline.

attached please see image for more detatil

.[image]

Answer (score -1):

Get all points from model space.

Create Polyline3d using these points.